# Can the image of a set over a discontinuous function contain infinity?

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, convex-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

If I were to define a "function" mapping $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\infty & x = 0\\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$ would this be consistent with definition of a function? (It is possible that this question comes down whether or not $\infty \in \mathbb{R}$ makes sense to write).

Is there anything about this mapping that indicates that it is NOT a function?

Comment: The title is not good, I mean not meaningful

Comment: How do you define $\infty$?

Comment: @Physor yea I was having a hard time coming up with a good title. Any suggestions for fixing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is *not* a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ since $\infty \not\in \mathbb{R}$. It is a function $\mathbb{R} \to \bar{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ though.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful